# Has anyone used the Java robot class to execute keystrokes using remoteWebDriver on Selenium grid?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a test case where I need to enter keystrokes into a windows dialog that pops up. I can successfully do this using the Java robot class to enter the desired keystrokes into the dialog when I run my tests locally. But when I run the tests using Selenium Grid 2 the robot executes the keystrokes on the system that executes the test from my Eclipse IDE rather than on the intended test node remotely.

Anyone run into this or have any suggestions on how to get the robot commands to execute on the test node remotely?  I'm thinking java robot may not be the best solution for tests on a grid, but it was a last resort for me.

Thanks!

Comment: robot class always uses your "physical" keyboard and mouse. if you want to use it remotely, you have to connect to the other system via teamviewer or execute the robot on the other system directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this work very easily by using something called Robotil, which allows me to use the Robot class on a remote machine. This may be helpful for other people so I'll post the link here: http://codoid.com/robotil/